How can I seal this hole the gas tank comes with?
I was given an old Honda generator that's in pretty good shape, except the gas tank was unsalvageably rusty. Luckily, I was able to order a replacement tank, but it has a hole where a fuel level meter is supposed to go. Unfortunately, the meter mounted in the old tank is in pretty bad shape too, but I can't find that part available anywhere.
I'm not that concerned about not having a fuel meter, but I need to do something about the hole for it. I put a picture below for reference. It's a metal tank and the hole is on top, maybe 1 to 1.5 inches in diameter. In the picture, it's the hole on the left.
What can I do to patch it?

Here are a couple pictures of the old part:



Can you use a blanking grommet?

@WeatherVane Possibly, but the hole does have those two notches for the tabs on the fuel meter. I'm not sure if those would be a problem.

If you don't care what it looks like duct tape will work just fine. I googled 'generator fuel tank float gauge' and it came up with plenty of options that would fit in that hole.

Whether or not the old fuel gauge works, is it serviceable enough can you install it to plug the hole? If you remove everything about the fuel gauge which isn't needed, then just install it back into the hole, it should seal it up and give you your plug.

I added some pictures. As rusty as it is, I think it would probably hold if I installed it again. I can cut the float off and clean it up with a wire brush. My main worry was if it would deteriorate further. Is there something I can do to try and slow/stop it from continuing to rust?

There's products you can get which coats the inside of gas tanks to prevent further deterioration. Not sure if I'd personally get enough to do the entire tank just for the "plug". You can, however, put the part in vinegar (or maybe Evaporust) to remove whatever rust is there, then clean it up as good as possible. Then, going forward, use something like Sta-Bil to stabilize the fuel and keep it from absorbing water.
